# Can I use python-escpos-printer with zebra zp500 label printer?

Tags: python, usb, zebra-printers

I am going to print labels to zebra zp500 label printer.
I found a python package and am not sure if I can use it with zebra zp500 label printer.
This is the source code I found on python-escpos-printer package documentation.

```
from escpos.connections import getUSBPrinter


printer = getUSBPrinter()(idVendor=0x1504,  # USB vendor and product Ids for Bixolon SRP-350plus
                          idProduct=0x0006  # printer
                          inputEndPoint=0x82,
                          outputEndPoint=0x01)

printer.text("Hello World")
printer.lf()
```

Can anyone help me figure out if I can use this package with zebra label printer

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO!. I've googled the library you're working with and the documentation for escpos in github links to a databse of printers which work with the library, you can definitely take a look at that and verify your specific model works.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the database of printers and zebra printer is not listed there. It seems like I cannot use the package. Do you have any recommendations on what package to use with zebra label printers?